# docker-compose error: volume is needed not string

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm starting to learn about docker and I want to run a nextcloud using the docker-compose file.

The docker-compose file I am using. I only specified the volumes which are folders I have created.

```
version: ‘2’

volumes:
nextcloud:/home/ahmed/Desktop/docker-storage/nextcloud
db:/home/ahmed/Desktop/docker-storage/db

services:
db:
image: mariadb
restart: always
volumes:
- db:/var/lib/mysql
environment:
- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD= anha1985
- MYSQL_PASSWORD= anha1985
- MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
- MYSQL_USER=nextcloud

app:
image: nextcloud
ports:
- 8080:80
links:
- db
volumes:
- nextcloud:/var/www/html
restart: always
```

The error message that I have is.
ERROR: In file ‘./docker-compose.yml’, volume must be a mapping, not a string.

Please advice me.

Comment: ./nextcloud:<whatever>

Comment: please explain more. where should I do this?

Comment: I think @BugHunter is saying that the volume syntax requires that the left of the colon needs to be an absolute path. https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/3189

Comment: The yml file syntax is sensitive to linefeeds and whitespace. Please edit your question with code formatting to include the file exactly as you have it, including the exact same indentation.

Answer (score 0):

The volume section at the top of the compose file is for defining named volumes. If you only have host volumes with an absolute or relative path, then you would only define the volume within each service. For a named volume, you would define it both at the top level and within each service that needs access to the named volume. These two sections, while named similarly, have a different syntax.

See this documentation for the volume section at the top level of the yml file: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference

And this documentation applies to the volume section within each service: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes